# Direct ping is not working

Tags: networking, routing, ping

`ping -I eth1 10.5.48.2` is working but `ping 10.5.48.2` is not working
this is my **route**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         Docsis-Gateway. 0.0.0.0         UG    20     0        0 wlan0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
10.1.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     20     0        0 wlan0
10.5.48.0       _gateway        255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 eth1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.13.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eth1
```

but the same configuration is working in another system

Comment: OK. What is the problem? Or question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `ip route get 10.5.48.2` to show what route is matching. What is the IP of the `eth1` interface and `_gateway`? Please add the output of `ip route show table local` and `ip route show table main`, since `route` only shows one of the routing tables